# How can I create a column in a dataframe using conditional logic on multiple columns in another dataframe python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take the result value associated with the latest date in my dataframe, and create a new dataframe containing 'location', 'latest_date', and 'latest_result'. I have tried the following code:

```html
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('SL_report_table.xlsx')
df = df.dropna(subset=['RESULT'])
df.head()
LOCATION    TYPE    DATE    EVENT   RESULT  D_RESULT    FLAG    UNITS
20  AS-01   NaN 2020-11-07 13:35:00 44142.565972    100.0   1.0 NaN ug/L
21  AS-01   NaN 2020-06-16 00:00:00 43998.000000    250.0   1.0 NaN ug/L
22  AS-01   NaN 2019-10-08 13:30:00 43746.562500    260.0   1.0 NaN ug/L
23  AS-01   NaN 2019-05-14 21:40:00 43599.902778    230.0   1.0 NaN ug/L
24  AS-01   NaN 2018-10-03 15:00:00 43376.625000    100.0   0.0 NaN ug/L
grouped_maxdate = df.groupby('LOCATION').DATE.max()
grouped_maxdate = grouped_maxdate.to_frame()

for row in df:
    if row['LOCATION'] == grouped_maxdate['LOCATION'] and row['DATE'] == grouped_maxdate['LOCTION']:
        grouped_maxdate['LAST_RESULT'] = df['RESULT']
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What should be your expected dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort values by `DATE` and keep the last row for each `LOCATION` group:

```
>>> df.sort_values('DATE').groupby('LOCATION').last()

          TYPE                 DATE         EVENT  RESULT  D_RESULT  FLAG UNITS
LOCATION
AS-01      NaN  2020-11-07 13:35:00  44142.565972   100.0       1.0   NaN  ug/L
```

Full code:

```
out = df[['LOCATION', 'DATE', 'RESULT']].sort_values('DATE').groupby('LOCATION', as_index=False).last()

out.columns = ['location', 'latest_date', 'latest_result']
```

```
>>> out
  location          latest_date  latest_result
0    AS-01  2020-11-07 13:35:00          100.0
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the '\' do in creating the 'out' dataframe?

Comment: '\' is to indicate that a statement is continued on the next line. It's just for better display on StackOverflow. I removed them, now there is an horizontal scroll bar to view the full line of code.